# Is there a way to get Nashorn code completion working in any IDE?

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

I am writing some Nashorn javascript code. It is loaded via a Java method something roughly like this:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine scriptEngine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
CompiledScript compiledScript = ((Compilable) scriptEngine).compile(getConfiguration().getScript());
ScriptContext ctx = scriptEngine.getContext();
ctx.setAttribute("logger", LOG, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
ctx.setAttribute("customPojo", customPojo, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
Object evaluatedScript = compiledScript.eval(ctx);
Object ret = ((Invocable) scriptEngine).invokeMethod(evaluatedScript, "call", evaluatedScript, message.request, message.response.orNull(), context, anotherCustomPojo);
```

This works great. Sow now the developer can provide the JavaScript snippet something like:

```
function (request, response, ctx, customPojo, anotherCustomPojo) { 
   // use the objects
}
```

Each of these parameters for the function are actually typed Java objects through nashorn now. But without code completion, developers are left reading javadoc and leads to a less-than-pleasant experience.

Does anyone have Nashorn working with an IDE who could share me the process of how to do it?

I don't care what IDE it is... just want some basic code completion. It seems like a bit of a difficult task for someone to have set this up but perhaps it somehow exists?

I see this guide: http://romsteady.blogspot.com/2015/05/enabling-nashorn-autocompleteintellisen.html
but it is fairly greek to me. I don't get what it's getting at. Is it saying that I need to create JavaDoc-for-javascript that tells the IDE what classes are being expected so that it can do the auto complete? Could really use a better example.

I'd prefer IntelliJ or Eclipse IDE to do this... but I don't really care what IDE as long as it works. Any ideas?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I'm going to guess that that's not possible. Since javascript isn't actually typed, a regular IDE is going to have trouble auto-completing. I haven't seen any plugins that will do this, either.

Comment: yep. so far by cruising the `##java` irc room i've found that you can get Nashorn to auto complete basic java stuff. but not those typed parameters.

Comment: @jordaniac89 check this out https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt162307.aspx - something like this is what i'm lookin for